# Restart Process using specific port

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm still writing my websockets app and I've run into an issue.  Due to my host (Bluehost) preventing any single process from running longer than about an hour, I have a cron job to restart my server every x min (1, 5, 10, 30 tried)

```
>killall -w php; php -n /home/myurl/Serv/serv.php
```

But the issue is that while I run my server directly via ssh and get no errors, any time I try to run it via cron job or background process (append &), the server will either fail to socket bind or connect and then terminate after first client message.  I've done some reading and one forum said this could be due to the socket still being considered "occupied" after I kill the previous process.  I've also been noticing "killall -w php" isn't always getting the job done in killing processes, but this could be related to the socket bind issue.

Bottom line the command doesn't work properly when executed by cron job but does when executed by ssh.  Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: It sure sounds like you should be using a host that "supports" what you're trying to do rather than a host that actively tries to prevent what you're doing.

Comment: Bluehost came highly rec'd and I didn't quite know this could be a sticking point.  And I can't think of any serverspace with shared resources that allow scripts to run indefinitely.  I'd have to fork out for private resources.  And in case of memory issues it'd be good to have a server that resets occasionally.  I'd like to move on from this though and solve the problem at hand.  Any ideas on the socket?